# How to use render () in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and trying to get Render() to work.

I couldn't get the content to be added to my html page.

This is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script async src="/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>It works!</h1>
    );
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

I have tried not using a js referenced code, but both do not work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your first html has async script tag, the content might be loaded but not the script. Second html, ReactDOM is loaded from where ?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Oh, yes. The second html has an error: bundle.js:304 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: @earthyearth that is because it load before the div id app.

Comment: @T4rk1n I called the bundle.js on the head. Is that not loaded?

Comment: do I change to <script type="text/babel" src="bundle.js">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the dom you just need to put the script tag after the element you want to render on.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React app</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In main.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

No need to put a event listener that way.

Comment: I moved <script src="/bundle.js"></script> after <div id="app"></div> and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @earthyearth did you remove the event listener ?

Comment: @earthyearth There must be something else in your files or configs because I use this all the time and it works. [fiddle with your class](https://jsfiddle.net/03Lsypzz/1/).

Comment: I think so too. The error I got is in this function in my bundle.js

function invariant(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) ; does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @earthyearth try `console.log(document.getElementById('app')` before render.

Comment: @earthyearth look like some babel error, probably missing some plugin, mind sharing your webpack config ?

Comment: const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};

Comment: @earthyearth Your missing the presets ['env', 'react'] in loaders configs. I use webpack 2, might be different for another version but [here's what I use](https://gist.github.com/T4rk1n/042de528a27dd1e60a70a06c557e74c4).

Comment: okay. I'll look into that, but I tried another sample that I was following using the same config and it works.

Comment: There's a difference though. There's a createElement method first.
https://github.com/earthyearth/react_start_trial/blob/master/src/main.js

Comment: @earthyearth was this the error `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid` ?

Comment: i got it to work with the listener. I'll try to get it to work without.